# How can I increase the scrolling sensitivity in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, scroll

I've encountered a weird issue in which that the mouse wheel scrolling sensitivity when browsing code is slow, but however when I open an older project the mouse's scrolling speed is normal.

If I create a brand new project, scrolling speed is normal.

It should be like this:

[image]

..but is instead like this (from an older project):

[image]

I've looked around but however the only results suggest increasing the DPI on the screen, but however this can't be right since the scrolling speed differs between projects on the same computer.

How can I reset the scrolling speed of my project's code back to normal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Turns out that it's an issue related to Windows 8, 8.1, and earlier versions of 10.

I had set the scrolling speed via `PC Settings`, but however (for some unknown reason) there seems to be *two* separate settings for the mouse scrolling speed: one for `PC Settings` and one for `Control Panel`.

This issue is simple to resolve; simply adjust the mouse's scrolling speed via `Control Panel` instead of `Settings`. Doing this also seems to change the `PC Settings`' value also.

**This is no longer an issue with Windows 10 since the November 2015 update, with Visual Studio 2017. It is present in Visual Studio 2019, to fix this you'll want to [refer to Swifty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374557/2422013).**

Comment: This is one hell of an odd bug in windows 10, thanks for posting your answer I've not been able to figure this out for months!!

Comment: Windows 10, 1607, had the same issue. Went to control panel but settings there were already set. _Just clicking OK button_ with existing values resolved the issue.

Comment: Fully updated win10, still randomly encountered this issue. But yes, just opening the mouse settings and saving them resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: I am running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017 and encountered the same problem, which this also corrected. I just opened the mouse settings in control panel, changed the Wheel/Vertical Scrolling setting to 4 then back to 3, and hit apply. Visual Studio immediately began scrolling correctly.

Comment: *Note: As soon as I entered debug mode the problem came back. This is clearly a Visual Studio 2017 bug.

Comment: @JRodd A bug *in* VS2017, since this question pertained to VS2013. Anyhow, if you find a fix for the bug coming back in Debug mode, ensure to add an answer and suggest an edit to my question to add additional applicable tags :-).

Comment: Seems like this is an ongoing shameful lazy decision not be fixed for good. I have the same ultra fast scrolling on a laptop touchpad with the latest 2021-08-19 (V 1.59) ... the only way to work around this is to attach mouse with a wheel - and that works well.

Answer (score 40):

This problem is still happening in 2020. I'm using VS 2019 Community with the latest Windows 10 update. I had to go here in the `Options` dialog to change the scroll speed.

`Tools >> Options... >> Text Editor >> Advanced >> Scrolling sensitivity`

From there, you can adjust the vertical and horizontal scrolling speeds.

[image]

Comment: Although my question referred to Visual Studio 2013 and 2017 specifically, I've updated both my question and answer to broaden them to all Visual Studio versions. It's a shame that Microsoft has made this convoluted since it something as simple as scrolling sensitivity really doesn't need to be.

Comment: TYVM, this has solved my issue when scrolling within editor windows, which was actually the opposite to the OP's situation...scrolling was super fast such that I could reach the bottom of a *really* long code file within milliseconds lol. I'm still having the same issue in other UI windows though...do you have any idea how to change the scrolling sensitivity across *the entire application*? i.e. Solution Explorer, the Go To... window, etc.?

Comment: @Kenny83 You can probably try adjusting the windows system wide mouse scroll speed setting from the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered that issue, too. On my machine (a notebook), it appears to happen under the following circumstances: I open VS2017 without external monitor first. When I then plug in the external monitor and move the VS-window onto there, then the scorlling-speed is super-slow. Closing and reopening VS solves the issue in this situation. Probably, opening a new project will also reset VS appropriately, so this might be a viable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the registry editor
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPad`
3. Then set the `scrollControll_mode` value to `1`.

[image]

[Via Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3lhmhq/win10_elan_touchpad_scrolling_issues/)

Comment: This answer only applies if you use a laptop and have a specific brand of touchpad. This entire answer is also [plagiarised from a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3lhmhq/win10_elan_touchpad_scrolling_issues/).